# Splitting vectors

Tags: java, oop

I am working on a program that will scramble a word and the person has to guess that word.

**How do I split a vector of strings into two vectors of strings?**

I am given a Vector of Strings from a text file that has a word:hint type of layout. The word is separated by a colon from the hint. I need to create two vectors that separate each word but keep it associated with the hint so that when I click "hint" the correct hint comes up.

I've tried creating a loop but I'm not exactly sure how the loop should be stated. I'm pretty much lost here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Appreciate this is homework, but I'm shocked an assignment teaching Java is still using Vector...!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Loop through your original Vector and for each word:hint item, split them into two separate Strings and add them to two new Vectors.

Since you are adding them into two Vectors, the word and hint will have the same index on the two vectors. That will keep them "associated".

Comment: Using a HashMap or Hashtable would be better, then you do the lookup with the word you want. ex: `HashMap<String,String> myWordsAndHints = ...; String hint = myWordsAndHints.get( "myword" );`

Comment: It was marked as homework, so I'm assuming the question asks for Vectors. But if not, then yes .. a Map would be better.

Comment: I hope they were not instructed to use `Vector`s; they have been deprecated for about a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [String.split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

You can store the words/hints in two arrays with the same index, or you can put them in a [HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with `map.put(wordA, hintA)`.  A `HashMap` won't keep the order of the words; if you do need to maintain the order, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I simply implemented what the others said. Instead of using a LinkedHashMap, I just stored the keys on the fly and recounted them in that order. It should generally be a feature of your program to give them at random though. That'd be a funner game, right?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SOTest {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
            int numberofwords = 2;
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(numberofwords);
            Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
            v.add("noobs:snobo");
            v.add("words:osrwd");

            String tmp; String tmpArray [];
            String keys [] = new String [numberofwords];
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                    tmp = v.get(i);
                    tmpArray = tmp.split(":");
                    map.put(tmpArray[1], tmpArray[0]);
                    keys[i] = tmpArray[1];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("hint[" + i + "]: " + keys[i] + "\n\tword: " + map.get(keys[i]));
            }
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ javac SOTest.java && java SOTest
 hint[0]: snobo
word: noobs
 hint[1]: osrwd
word: words
```